# how to convert a picture(a.jpg or a.png) to "PCX"(a.pcx) format , using Objective-C in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pcx

I want to use my iPad to print a picture through a POSTEK printer,but it's not support "PNG" or "JPG". How to convert a picture to "PCX" format?

Comment: It seems that FFMpeg can do encode/record pcx file, so you may be able to do something from there: https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.5/pcx_8c-source.html

Comment: thinks , but it can not work...